# Border around my page with jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.2.0 on my page, for some reason its adding a border to my page and a message at the bottom of the page saying "loading".
When I delete the the jQuery mobile from my page there is no border or message.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfotX.jpg

Comment: Have you included the CSS too?

Comment: You should post the code you're using, otherwise we don't have a starting place to help you.

Comment: You right, I didnt include the CSS file, it's working now. But now the background is gray for some reason..